# Why job-foregrounding of gdb is losing it?

Tags: bash, shell, gdb, sh, job-control

I have a script that starts a server, then bunch of clients, then I need to foreground the server back, so I could test something. For some reason the server quickly quits, as if per some signal, so I wanted to inspect it with gdb.

The problem is, foregrounded gdb gets detached upon executing `run` command. Here's an example in plain `sh` *(`--nh` is for gdb to ignore config)*:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh -m

gdb --nh -q /bin/test &
sleep 1
fg
$ ./test.sh 
Reading symbols from /bin/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
gdb --nh -q /bin/test
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/test 
$ ps aux | grep gdb
constan+ 11418  1.5  0.3 104928 28200 pts/1    Tl   16:52   0:00 gdb --nh -q /bin/test
constan+ 11470  0.0  0.0  12100  2452 pts/1    S+   16:52   0:00 grep gdb
```

You can see, it got detached from the shell, and hangs there in list of processes.

With `zsh` and `bash` I'm additionally often getting the following errors:

```
[setting tty state failed in terminal_inferior: Input/output error]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
```

…and gdb does not appear in process list. But sometimes *(not very often)* behavior in `zsh` and `bash` is the same as with `sh`, i.e. there's no errors, and gdb gets detached.

All in all, what's going on with gdb?

Comment: FTR, though the question still holds, but I figured out the local situation with server — it turned out to be as simple as that I had to pass its job id to `fg`. I thought it might be the same with gdb, but doesn't seem so.

Comment: Isn't /usr/bin/test a program different from /bin/test?

Comment: @rostamn739 that would be weird, because both `/bin` and `/usr/bin` supposed to be in $PATH, which would result in weird conflicts. FWIW though, on my Archlinux `/bin` isn't in $PATH, but it's because here `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`.